# How to access a child Element of a node that is not an XML tag in XOM?

Tags: xml, xom

How do I access the = child element of the done node as shown in code below in XOM?

```
<done>=<start></start></done>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the `done` `Element` node, then `done.getChild(0)` would give you a `Text` node and which you can call `getValue()` to get a `String` with `=`.